# How to create a custom wordpress plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm learning plugin development and need to create a plugin that contains:

1. Add menu item and page in Admin Panel of WordPress
2. on that page, let us add text messages using a form having a text area and button.
3. it should show the added text messages as message boxes in the WordPress admin panel.
4. it should let us add/delete/update the messages.

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: The Admin Messages
Plugin URI: https://wpsaints.com
Author: Wp saints
Author URI: https://wpsaints.com
Version: 9.0
*/

function the_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Form', 'Form Items', 'manage_options', 'mypage', 'the_admin_menu_page', ' dashicons-menu', 6 );
    
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'the_admin_menu' );


function the_admin_menu_page() {
    
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <br><br>
        <lable><b>Enter your Message</b></lable>
        <br><br>
        <textarea></textarea><br><br>
        <button> Submit</button>


    </form>
    
    <?php
    
    function jal_install() {
        global $wpdb;
        
        $table_name = $wpdb->giftmix . "messagebox";
    }
    
    global $wpdb;
    
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $entermessage (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
      name tinytext NOT NULL,
      text text NOT NULL,
      url varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == "POST" ) {
        
        
        $Enter = ( $_POST[ "YourName" ] );
        $Email = ( $_POST[ "Email" ] );
    }
}
```

I have created this but now need suggestions from seniours on what to do next?
Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can also tell us what you tried to do so we might help you better. Your post is not really a question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a question, but as a not really an aswer, here are a few guidelines that you should keep in mind.

**Code convention**

Always try to prefix your functions with something unique (ex. your company name). This will be used like a namespace to avoid function name collision.

**Database**

Creating and updating a custom database table should be done in the plugin activation process, not during a custom function call.

```php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'pluginprefix_function_to_run' );
```

[More information on the process here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/).

**PHP**

It looks like your code is defining a PHP function inside another. That's not how you should do it. Functions should all be declared at the same level (or better, in a `class`).

**WordPress**

WP let you store almost everything you want in the `wp_options` table. If you need to add a custom config (like your admin field), you should try to store it in this table.
You can easily set and get options with

```php
$value = get_option( 'my_custom_option_name' );
update_option( 'my_custom_option_name', 'new value here')
```

Link to the docs [get_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) and [update_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/)

Next step for you might be to try to add this value somewhere in a page with a [short code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) or in your theme.